# How to pass exception to caller

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

This seems like is has to be simple, but I'm having trouble finding a simple straight forward answer.

Consider the following:

```
Sub Caller()
  Try
    Callee()
  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(Ex.Message)
  End Try
End Sub

Sub Callee()
  Try
    'Generate an error
  Catch ex As Exception
    'Pass the exception back to Caller.
    'I tried using 'throw' but it errored out inside this function
  End Try
End Sub
```

How do I not handle the exception inside `Callee` and instead pass the exception back to `Caller`?

This is a highly simplified view of some code that actually uses functions that return data already. So, I can't use a function with a return value to pass back the exception.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to catch an exception in a method then a good start would be to not write code in that method to catch an exception.

Comment: `Throw` in `Callee` should have worked: that will rethrow the original exception, and it can be caught by anything higher up the call chain.  If it failed, then there is something else going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want `Caller` to handle the exception, then remove the Try-Catch block from the `Callee` method. Any exception thrown by the `Callee` method will automatically be caught within the Try-Catch block inside the `Caller` method.